# How are these meshes being moved up while their origins are NOT moving?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I watched a tutorial and at one point, the person moved their objects up the Z axis, **but the origins did NOT move!**

[image]

I watched the screencast keys, but I still can't figure out how it was done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are moving the geometry in [*Edit Mode*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes).

1. Toggle edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or select it from the header:

   [image]
2. Select all geometry with <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to move the selection along the Z axis.

Answer (score 3):

That is in edit mode, with  all the verts selected, so the while mesh is moving. In edit mode the origin will not move.